# How to convert a chron object to a numerical object of seconds since an origin in R

Tags: r, time, chron

I have a chron object like this:

```
 t <- as.chron("06/01/13 01:00:00", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

and I want to convert it to seconds from origin, where the origin is:

```
 or <- "06/01/13 00:00:00"
```

so what I want is that the object t become:

```
 t <- 3600
```

Thank you very much
Giulia

Comment: `as.numeric(t-as.chron("06/01/13 00:00:00", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))*24*3600`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `difftime()`:

```
R> library(chron)
R>  t <- as.chron("06/01/13 01:00:00", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S") 
R> or <- as.chron("06/01/13 00:00:00", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S") 
R> difftime(t, or)
Time difference of 1 hours
R>
```

or in the units you want:

```
R> difftime(t, or, unit="secs")
Time difference of 3600 secs
R> as.numeric(difftime(t, or, unit="secs"))
[1] 3600
R>
```

As an aside, you probably want to use `POSIXct` instead of `chron` which `difftime()` converts to for you anyway. See `help(DateTimeClasses)`.

Comment: But beware that if you use POSIXct that you can then get subtle time zone problems which are not a problem if you stick with chron.

Comment: Though in this case with straight differences that should not matter.

Comment: Yes, its not likely that you will get in trouble with this specific operation but the implication is that you are using it more generally in which case you could.